# How to Interpret ggmap stat_density2d plots

Tags: r

How to interpret ggmap plots. What does the level legend indicate in my plot below ?

Is it the number of counts of rows in a dataframe?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the function?

Comment: Yes. I didn't  get any answer for ..level..

Answer (score 0):

Level indicates the density of your dependent variable within the geospatial area displayed.

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for your answer. Do you know the formulae used to calculate it. If it is related to geospatial area, then what distance unit(feet,squareinches,km) is considered for calculating level ?